# Launch Activity for a certain record

Tags: android

I have an screen that displays all the names in the Contacts in a ListView.

When the user clicks on a name, I want to launch another Activity which display the details of the selected Contact (Phone number/ email) in another screen. How do I display details for the *selected* row. (i.e When starting the intent how do I send over the row_id of the item selected)?

I've tried the following code:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ContactDetails.class);
    startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package it as an extra:

```
i.putExtra("MyReallyCoolContactID", id);
```

Then, `ContactDetails` can call `getIntent().getExtra("MyReallyCoolContactID")` to get the ID of the contact of interest.

Comment: Thanks! You answer was very helpful.
The only change I made was that, since I couldn't find Intent.getExtra(String) method, I used the following:  

  Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
  long id = (Long)b.get("MyReallyCoolContactID");